# Multi Threading issue in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have an application hosted on my server. this application sends emails to list of users. lets say the list have 10000 users. i divide the list into three parts and assign each to a seperate thread to send emails. The issue is when i go to the server where i hosted my application and run the application, it sends the emails to all the 3 list i have created,
but when i browse the application remotely on my local pc. the emails is not sending.

can anybody help me what is the issue and how to resolve it.

thanks in advance
regards

Comment: maybe you need to define smtp or somthing like that?

Comment: Errors, Screenshots, Code? describe the scenario better please.

Comment: That's two different problems. Sends emails to all three lists is almost certainly a logic error so we'd need some code. the split and the eamil call that passed the list. The remote issue could be almost anything....

Comment: i have posted the code as under.

Answer (score 0):

Hi here is the code.

```
# region /////Split Users List in 3 Parts////
                ArrayList thList1 = new ArrayList();
                ArrayList thList2 = new ArrayList();
                ArrayList thList3 = new ArrayList();
                ArrayList thListId1 = new ArrayList();
                ArrayList thListId2 = new ArrayList();
                ArrayList thListId3 = new ArrayList();
                int countList = arlistuid.Count / 3;
                int count;
                for (count = 0; count < arlistuid.Count; count++)
                {
                    if (count < countList)
                    {
                        thList1.Add(arlistuid[count]);
                        thListId1.Add(arlistid[count]);
                    }
                    else if (count >= countList && (count < countList + countList))
                    {
                        thList2.Add(arlistuid[count]);
                        thListId2.Add(arlistid[count]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        thList3.Add(arlistuid[count]);
                        thListId3.Add(arlistid[count]);
                    }

                }

                # endregion

                # region ///Send Email using 3 threads
                if (thList1.Count > 0)
                {
                    object thdargs = new object[2] { thList1, thListId1 };
                    Thread thd1 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(SplitListEmail));
                    thd1.IsBackground = true;
                    thd1.Name = "Thread1";
                    thd1.Start(thdargs);
                }
                if (thList2.Count > 0)
                {
                    object thd2args = new object[2] { thList2, thListId2 };
                    Thread thd2 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(SplitListEmail));
                    thd2.IsBackground = true;
                    thd2.Name = "Thread2";
                    thd2.Start(thd2args);
                }
                if (thList3.Count > 0)
                {
                    object thd3args = new object[2] { thList3, thListId3 };
                    Thread thd3 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(SplitListEmail));
                    thd3.IsBackground = true;
                    thd3.Name = "Thread3";
                    thd3.Start(thd3args);
                }
                # endregion
```